# Find all values in a list of maps that have the key "Oranges"

Tags: list, groovy, maps

Still new to groovy here but I am trying to obtain all values from each map in my list of maps that have a key equal to "Oranges"

```
def resultSet = [
["Oranges":123456, "Apples": "none"],["Oranges":7890, "Apples": "some"]
]
def fruit = resultSet.each{
    it.findAll{key, value -> key == "Oranges"}.value
}

println fruit
```

so for this, I would expect the result to be: `[123456, 7890]`
but I am getting: `[[Oranges:123456, Apples:none], [Oranges:7890, Apples:some]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return of the `each` method is the collection itself. You want to apply some kind of filter on the collection, and not on each of its items. I suggest using `findResults`, as it will filter out null and empty values:

```
def resultSet = [
    ["Oranges":123456, "Apples": "none"],
    ["Oranges":7890, "Apples": "some"]
]

def fruit = resultSet.findResults { it.Oranges?.value }

assert fruit == [123456, 7890]
```

Comment: Thanks @Will ! I thought for some reason that the each would be iterating over each map in my list. Didn't notice it was seeing it as one collection

Answer (score 1):

There is A simple solution:

```
def fruit = resultSet.Oranges


assert fruit == [123456, 7890]
```

Comment: Does this syntax have a name?

Comment: I have no idea TBH, I found it by mistake

Comment: That's a pitty. Thanks anyways! :) 
I have created a question here now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434133/groovy-enhancement-name-access-map-values-directly-in-a-list-of-maps