# Groovy enhancement name: Access map values directly in a List of Maps

Tags: groovy

Dear Groovy specialists,

I stumbled upon a phenomenon in Groovy which I would describe as follows:
Given a list of maps that share some common keys, it is possible to access the Map values directly via the List.

Example:

```
ArrayList people = [
        ["height": 172, "age": 42],
        ["height": 180, "age": 66],
        ["height": 180, "age": null],
        ["height": 180],
        ["age": 10]
]

println "people.height: " + people.height
println "people.age: " + people.age
```

Output:

```
people.height: [172, 180, 180, 180, null]
people.age: [42, 66, null, null, 10]
```

Does this syntax (e.g. `people.height` / `people.age`) have a name?

Thanks in advance!

PS: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71586670/6853900) would be another example of the mentioned syntax

Comment: You use the key as if it is a property with dot syntax.

Comment: You should be using the `spread operator` to avoid ambiguity of referencing the Map's fields using `dot-notation` or `subscript operator`: `people*.height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this syntax (e.g. people.height / people.age) have a name?

That is Groovy's syntax for property access.

*(Note that a property is a different thing than a field and Groovy has a bunch of special dynamic stuff that happens during property access.)*